# Wrong values for Data

Tags: android

I have a problem with Date. I get date using: `measure.getDate()` and I got 0 Sun Jun 09 14:09:00 CEST 2012 result in my Log. But when I use `measure.getDate().getDay())` I got `0`, for `measure.getDate().getMonth()` I got result `5` for `measure.getDate().getYear())` I got 112. How I can get good format of day, month and your?

```
JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            List<Measure> measures = new Measure.BuilderJSON().buildList(jsonArray);
            for(Measure measure: measures){
                addParamsToLists(measure);
                Log.v("eqwdasfas1", ""+measure.getDate().getDay());
                Log.v("eqwdasfas2", ""+measure.getDate().getDate());
                Log.v("eqwdasfas3", ""+measure.getDate().getYear());
                Log.v("eqwdasfas4", ""+measure.getDate().getMonth());
                Log.v("eqwdasfas5", ""+measure.getDate());
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't know why getDate() return good value and  other functions return wrong

Comment: Post your Measure class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for `Date`:

> In all methods of class Date that accept or return year, month, date, hours, minutes, and seconds values, the following representations are used:
>
> A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.
>
> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.
>
> A date (day of month) is represented by an integer from 1 to 31 in the usual manner.
>   An hour is represented by an integer from 0 to 23. Thus, the hour from midnight to 1 a.m. is hour 0, and the hour from noon to 1 p.m. is hour 12.
>
> A minute is represented by an integer from 0 to 59 in the usual manner.
>
> A second is represented by an integer from 0 to 61; the values 60 and 61 occur only for leap seconds and even then only in Java implementations that actually track leap seconds correctly.

So, for your issues, June *is* 5, Sunday *is* 0, and `112 = (2012 - 1900)`.